# Reference Request: Computer program for calculating conical hull

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, convex-hulls, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose we are given several vectors $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m$ in an $n$-dimensional space. The convex cone spanned by them is defined to be the set
\begin{equation}
C=\{\sum_{i=1}^mt_i\alpha_i|\ t_i\ge0,\forall i\}.
\end{equation}

However, computing the condition of this cone by hand is usually hard. Besides, I also need to compute the intersection of two convex cones, which is even harder. Does anyone know any online calculator or math programs to do this? Sorry I am really bad at computers...

Thank you so much for your kind help!

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm, or a software library?

Comment: A software, I just want to compute some of my examples.